# C++: When there's an object inside another object created using constructor, does that inner object live in the stack or the heap?

Tags: heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm wondering where a struct inside a struct created from the constructor (by the "new" keyword) lives: is it in the stack or the heap?
Let's say I have these definitions to create a singly linked list:

```
struct Employee{
   int code;
   string name;
   double wage;
};

struct Node {
    Employee employee;
    Node* next;
};
```

Whenever I create a pointer to a Node and then I assign `new Node()` to it, I understand I'm creating a Node object in the heap, and its fields can be dereferenced using the -> operator. But when I try to access a field of the inner struct I need to use the dot (.) operator, such as:

```
Node* pointer = new Node();
pointer->employee.name="John Doe";
```

So this makes me wonder if the Employee object was created inside the stack or the heap.
Basically: when an object is created in the heap, do all inner objects in its member variables get created in the heap as well?

Thanks!

Comment: It lives where the outer object lives IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still in the heap! The 'new' operation will malloc on the heap about sizeof(Node) bytes, and it equals sizeof(Employee)+sizeof(Node*), so name is on the heap. 
And you should know '.' is just a way for C/C++ compiler to access some member, it does nothing about memory about heap or stack.

Answer (score 1):

`->` and `.` have nothing to do whether the element lives on heap or stack.  A `->` is used, when you have a *pointer*, a `.` when you have an *object*.  You could create a struct on the stack and access its values using a pointer:

```
struct Foo
{
  int i;
};
Foo f; // object on stack
f.i = 5; // access object
Foo* p_f = &f; // get pointer to address of object (which is still on the stack)
p_f->i = 3; // access object through pointer
```

To answer your question: the node that `pointer` points to lives in the heap and so does the string `pointer->employee.name`.

Please note, that `new` is not the constructor, but a function `Node()` would be the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Anything `new` lives on the heap and must be explicitly released by calling `delete`. Everything else is in the stack.